# if condition with multiple and conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I am using code which includes an `If` condition with multiple `And` conditions.

This code works fine until I am not using multiple `And` conditions but when I am using multiple `And` conditions there is error:

> Sub or function not defined.

I.e. when i am extending the code to next level as code line

Code is below:-

```
Sub main()

With Worksheets("Employee Data")

Sheets("Employee Data").Range("AQ4:AQ2000").Value = ""

If Range("F4") = "" Then
Range("AQ4") = ""
Else
If Range("F4").Value = "E1" And Range("AB4").Value = "Yes" Then
Range("AQ4").Formula = "=""Due for Promotion to E2A Level w.e.f."" &  TEXT(DATE(YEAR(AP4)+1,MONTH(AP4),DAY(AP4)),""DD-MMM-YYYY"")"
Else
If Range("F4") = "E1" And Range("AB4").Value = "No" Then
Range("AQ4").Formula = "=""Due for Promotion to E2A Level w.e.f."" &  TEXT(DATE(YEAR(AP4)+2,MONTH(AP4),DAY(AP4)),""DD-MMM-YYYY"")"
If Range("F4") = "E2" And Range("AB4").Value = "Yes" Then
Range("AQ4").Formula = "=""Due for Promotion to E2A Level w.e.f."" &  TEXT(DATE(YEAR(AP4)+1,MONTH(AP4),DAY(AP4)),""DD-MMM-YYYY"")"
Else
If Range("F4") = "E2A" And Range("AB4").Value = "Yes" Then
Range("AQ4").Formula = "=""Due for Promotion to E3 Level w.e.f."" &  TEXT(DATE(YEAR(AP4)+4,MONTH(AP4),DAY(AP4)),""DD-MMM-YYYY"")"

' error lies in this code line i.e. sub or function not defined

Else
If Range("F4") = "E2A" And Range("AB4").Value = "NO" And Ragne("P4").Value < 9 And Range("AE4").Value = "NA" Then
Range("AQ4").Formula = "=""Due for Promotion to E3 Level w.e.f."" &  TEXT(DATE(YEAR(AP4)+5,MONTH(AP4),DAY(AP4)),""DD-MMM-YYYY"")"
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End With
End Sub
```

Can anybody help please ?

Comment: You've got a typo on, or near, where you say the error is - you have `Ragne` instead of `Range`.

Comment: Your code is "Screaming" for the use of `Select Case Range("F4").Value` , with another `Case Range("AB4").Value`

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to use a proper indentation and you can make use of `ElseIf` to avoid too many `End If`.

(I know this is not an answer but too much to point out in a comment, and the question might get closed anyway due to a typo)

```
Sub main()
    With Worksheets("Employee Data")
        Sheets("Employee Data").Range("AQ4:AQ2000").Value = ""

        If Range("F4") = "" Then
            Range("AQ4") = ""
        ElseIf Range("F4").Value = "E1" And Range("AB4").Value = "Yes" Then
            Range("AQ4").Formula = "=""Due for Promotion to E2A Level w.e.f."" &  TEXT(DATE(YEAR(AP4)+1,MONTH(AP4),DAY(AP4)),""DD-MMM-YYYY"")"
        ElseIf Range("F4") = "E1" And Range("AB4").Value = "No" Then
            Range("AQ4").Formula = "=""Due for Promotion to E2A Level w.e.f."" &  TEXT(DATE(YEAR(AP4)+2,MONTH(AP4),DAY(AP4)),""DD-MMM-YYYY"")"
            If Range("F4") = "E2" And Range("AB4").Value = "Yes" Then
                Range("AQ4").Formula = "=""Due for Promotion to E2A Level w.e.f."" &  TEXT(DATE(YEAR(AP4)+1,MONTH(AP4),DAY(AP4)),""DD-MMM-YYYY"")"
            ElseIf Range("F4") = "E2A" And Range("AB4").Value = "Yes" Then
                Range("AQ4").Formula = "=""Due for Promotion to E3 Level w.e.f."" &  TEXT(DATE(YEAR(AP4)+4,MONTH(AP4),DAY(AP4)),""DD-MMM-YYYY"")"
            ElseIf Range("F4") = "E2A" And Range("AB4").Value = "NO" And Range("P4").Value < 9 And Range("AE4").Value = "NA" Then
                Range("AQ4").Formula = "=""Due for Promotion to E3 Level w.e.f."" &  TEXT(DATE(YEAR(AP4)+5,MONTH(AP4),DAY(AP4)),""DD-MMM-YYYY"")"
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```